# How to store json data from a POST response in a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, post, google-chrome-extension, store

I am developing a chrome extentsion. when user loads a page in browser a POST request is sent to server and response back with json objects. I want to store that json object so that further i can add this json value in my GET request .
I have found few options to store GET response but did not find out yet how to store POST response !
Can anyone help me with some links or with an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into chrome.storage to store data if that is what you mean:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: I need to store the post response somewhere in the code to reuse it  for making another GET request .

Comment: Do you have to perform the GET directly after the post? Why not assigning the POST response to a variable then?

Comment: no . GET response should perform if user wants to click on icon.

Comment: So ? If you store it in a variable, you can use this variable in onClick event handler.